# Is there a more efficient C# CryptoStream implementation for streaming decryption of large files

Tags: c#, .net, performance, encryption, cryptography

I am using LibVLC and Unity to playback locally stored encrypted 360 videos. VLC's Unity package has a feature to play content via a C# stream. I am using a FileStream wrapped in a CryptoStream to get this working. This works for medium to small videos however, larger, high bitrate videos don't playback properly with my current implementation.

I am using the following code to create a decrypting CryptoStream which is passed to VLC. The path points to a properly encrypted file stored on device.

```
AesCryptoServiceProvider aesCryptoServiceProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
FileStream crpytoFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(crpytoFileStream, aesCryptoServiceProvider.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
```

I am using AesCyptoServiceProvider because I know it is the faster cryptostream implementation. I have also tried some different options shown below however I haven't seen much improvement over the default options for AesCryptoServiceProvider.

```
aesCryptoServiceProvider.BlockSize = 128;
aesCryptoServiceProvider.KeySize = 256;
aesCryptoServiceProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
aesCryptoServiceProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.ANSIX923;
```

I've done quite a bit of research and I haven't been able to find definite ways of speeding up the CryptoStream. I don't know if there is a better way to wrap my streams or if there is something I am overlooking. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you are using a streaming implementation then the throughput (bytes per second) should be approximately the same no matter how large the file is.

Comment: I believe by larger files he means video's of a higher resolution, which need a higher bits per second throughput to be able to display smoothly.

Comment: Scott is correct for my application. I need to increase the speed of the cryptostream so that it can handle decoding and playing back video in real time.